# Solr installation error on tomcat 7

Tags: solr, tomcat7, digital-ocean

i followed all steps given in digital ocean document and installed tomcat 7 through apt-get.tomcat installed with any errors and also changed my port to 8181.
[https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-on-ubuntu-12-04](http://gregsomers.com/blog/2013/07/30/install-apache-solr-44-on-ubuntu-1204-with-tomcat-7-and-mysql-data-import)
but when i install solr ( followed all steps given in this document including copying jar files to lib folder http://gregsomers.com/blog/2013/07/30/install-apache-solr-44-on-ubuntu-1204-with-tomcat-7-and-mysql-data-import).

following errors shown in log files and solr is not getting started.Iam newbie to solr and tomcat. let me what this error means and how to fix

```
Dec 19, 2013 3:18:20 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: HTMLManager: start: Starting web application '/solr'
Dec 19, 2013 3:18:20 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
SEVERE: FAIL - Application at context path /solr could not be started
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: An invalid Lifecycle transition was attempted ([after_stop]) for component [org.apache.catalina.startup.FailedContext@425743] in state [FAILED]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.invalidTransition(LifecycleBase.java:408)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:249)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.start(ManagerServlet.java:1247)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.start(HTMLManagerServlet.java:747)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:222)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:194)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:581)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:307)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701)
Dec 19, 2013 3:18:20 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: HTMLManager: list: Listing contexts for virtual host 'localhost'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem with solr version. i installed 4.6 version instead of 4.4.